# Add to a delegate from a string

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a number of methods

```
public void A(){}
public void B(){}
```

etc

I then want to add one (or more) of these methods to the instances of my class following a string constructor:

```
class MyClass
{

    public delegate void Del();
    public Del MyDel;

    public MyClass(string myString)
    {

    }   
}
```

Inside the constructor i want to be able to add to my delegate the class method called myString, is it possible?

Comment: That string would have to identify an *object* since these methods are not static.  That's not practical.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Delegate.CreateDelegate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12f294ye(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
class MyClass
{

    public delegate void Del();
    public Del MyDel;

    public MyClass(string myString)
    {
        MyDel = (Del)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Del), this, myString);
    }

    public void A() { }
    public void B() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , put a break point in the anonymous method , in A() and in B()

```
    public delegate void Del();
    public Del MyDel;

    public MainWindow(string imAStringSentToAConstructorBySomeone)
    {         
        // Edit :

       MyDel += (Del)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Del), this,imAStringSentToAConstructorBySomeone);

       // Full Answer
        MyDel += () => 
        { 

        };

        MyDel += (Del)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Del), this, "A");
        MyDel += (Del)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Del), this, "B");

        MyDel.Invoke();
    }

    public void A() 
    {}

    public void B() 
    {}
```

Comment: and where would be my string?

Comment: so basically you copied the answer above... what does MyDel += () => 
        { 

        }; do different from it?

Comment: That's why i added it , to show you how you can Add More than one method to your delegate's invocation list .  
I extended the answer from above.

Comment: ' = ' would mean only one method , ' += ' would add to the delegate .